# Email notification of new post includes code

Tags: posts, subscription

One of my subscribers gets the following words at the beginning of the email of my latest post. Then part way through the post there is another string of code and further along there is another string of code.  I signed up also via the link on my blog to get email notification of my own new posts and my email doesn't show this code???

> **The Company Header**
>   by Company Owner
>
> ```
> Normal
> 0
> false
> false
> false
> EN-CA
> X-NONE
> X-NONE
> /* Style Definitions */
> table.MsoNormalTable
> {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
> mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
> mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
> mso-style-noshow:yes;
> mso-style-priority:99;
> mso-style-qformat:yes;
> mso-style-parent:"";
> mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
> mso-para-margin:0cm;
> mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
> mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
> font-size:11.0pt;
> font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
> mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
> mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
> mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
> mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;
> mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
> mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
> mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
> mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
> ```

Comment: You surely copied the content directly from the MS Word. Because that `MsoNormalTable` thing I found in the texts when copied directly from MS Word. Copying directly from MS Word takes some formatting along with it. So, try copying from MS Word, then paste it in any text editor (like Notepad), and then copy again from the Text Editor and then paste it into the WP Editor. Or, From MS Word paste directly into the WP Editor and then click on the **Remove Formatting** button to remove all the formatting and then format your texts again. :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam : that is a respectable answer. You should post it as such. Bonus (imaginary) points if you add screenshots.

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum. Posted the answer with screenshots. :)

Comment: Or while pasting make a right click and choose paste as plain text, that would remove all the formatting by default.

Answer (score 1):

You surely copied the content directly from the Microsoft Word. Because that `MsoNormalTable` thing I found in the texts when copied directly from MS Word. Copying directly from MS Word takes some formatting along with it. So, you can try any of the methods ***either*** :

- Copy the texts from MS Word, and paste them via **Paste From Word** paste button from the WP Editor.
  [image: Paste from Word]
- Try copying from MS Word » then paste it in any Text Editor (like Notepad) » then copy again from the Text Editor  » and then paste it into the WP Editor. And format the texts again.
- From MS Word paste directly into the WP Editor and then click on the Remove Formatting button to remove all the formatting and then format your texts again.
  [image: Remove Formatting]